# C# check internet connection If I use this wi-fi connection but do not log in

Tags: c#

There is a wi-fi connection here at work that requires login credentials of its own before data can transmit. If I use this wi-fi connection but do not log in. I want to check internet connection c#

I tried all these ways mentioned in below link nothing works.
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/147662/Testing-Internet-Connectivity

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate on what you want to do? Do you want to check if you can connect to the internet through that WIFI connection with or without authenticating? Please explain.

Comment: Yes I want to check my internet connectivity. If I dont enter the credential, network connection shows "limited" in my taskbar. In this case, I want to handle this and show user using c# code "Internet connection failed. Check connection and try again."

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your program needs internet connectivity to connect to a remote server some place. If that is the case I wouldn't worry too much about the details of how you are connected, the only important thing is that you are connected.

Easiest solution here might be to send a ping to that server to see if it can connect.

Something like this (paraphrased from an application of mine):

```
Ping ping = new Ping();
PingReply pr = null;
bool pingError = false;
try
{
    pr = ping.Send("http://myservername.fake", 5000);
}
catch
{
    pingError = true;
}
finally
{
    /* Short-curcuit here, because pr.Status might still be 
     null if no network connectivity at all. */

    if (pingError || pr.Status != IPStatus.Success)
    {
        // Here we know we are offline
    }
    else
    {
        // Here we know we are online
    }
}
```

Dependant on the reason for the failure, Ping will either throw exception, or return false, so this takes care of both potential options.

Comment: @ KingCronus this statement "pr = ping.Send(" http://google.com", 5000)" irrespective of good internet connection it sets pingError = true and pr always null.

Comment: @user3076123, I can assure you that it doesn't. I have this running in a production environment. Are you *sure* that you have direct internet access, and that there isn't some sort of proxy in the way?

Comment: Below code is working, but pingreply.status always "success" even when I use wificonnection with limited connectivity :(

                Ping myPing = new Ping();
                String host = "google.com";
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
                int timeout = 1000;
                PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();
                PingReply reply = myPing.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    return true;
                }

Comment: What happens if you try to ping Google from your PC without using this, i.e. from command prompt?

Comment: In my machine ping always work, thats my problem. when I navigate that page in browser it wont work. solution that are around ping concept wont work in my case, i believe